# Retrieve data into pre-define activity, based on onClick ListView data from Sqlite database

Tags: android, sqlite, listview, data-retrieval

I'm making a form. I've already done saving my data into database. Now I've done displaying specific data (code of form and date) to differentiate my forms into the list view. And when user click on item it will start pre-define activity and fill the columns with corresponding data.

For example: user sees 5 rows of list view items. He clicks on the second row and it will show the activity fill with corresponding data with this row. But when he clicks on the third row it will show in same activity different data. 
I've been trying for several days but i can't figured it out. I'm android beginner so it's almost impossible for me to do it on my own. So i would be very grateful for every help.

Here are same code's hope it's suffice.

**DataListActivity**

```
public class DataListActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    ListView listView;
    SQLiteDatabase sqLiteDatabase;
    DbOperace dbOperace;
    Cursor cursor;
    ListDataAdapter listDataAdapter;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.data_list_layout);

        listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.lis_view);
        listDataAdapter = new ListDataAdapter(getApplicationContext(),R.layout.row_layout);
        listView.setAdapter(listDataAdapter);

        dbOperace = new DbOperace(getApplicationContext());
        sqLiteDatabase = dbOperace.getReadableDatabase();
        cursor = dbOperace.getInformations(sqLiteDatabase);

        if (cursor.moveToFirst())
        {
            do {

                String kod,den;
                kod = cursor.getString(0);
                den = cursor.getString(1);
                DataProvider dataProvider = new DataProvider(kod,den);
                listDataAdapter.add(dataProvider);

            }while (cursor.moveToNext());
        }
    }
}
```

**DataProvider.java**

```
public class DataProvider {

    private String kod;
    private String den;

    public String getKod() {
        return kod;
    }

    public void setKod(String kod) {
        this.kod = kod;
    }

    public String getDen() {
        return den;
    }

    public void setDen(String den) {
        this.den = den;
    }

    public DataProvider(String kod, String den)
    {
        this.kod=kod;
        this.den=den;
    }
}
```

**DbOperations**

```
public Cursor getInformations(SQLiteDatabase db)
{
        Cursor cursor;
        String[] projections = {FormDatabase.FormularovaDatabaze.KOD_USEKU_KOMUNIKACE,
                FormDatabase.FormularovaDatabaze.DNE};
        cursor = db.query(FormDatabase.FormularovaDatabaze.JMENO_TABULKY,projections,null,null,null,null,null);
        return cursor;
}
```

**ListDataAdapter.java**

```
public class ListDataAdapter extends ArrayAdapter{
    List list = new ArrayList();

    public ListDataAdapter(Context context, int resource) {
        super(context, resource);
    }

    static class LayoutHandler
    {
        TextView kod,den;
    }

@Override
public void add(Object object) {
    super.add(object);
    list.add(object);
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return list.size();
}

@Override
public Object getItem(int position) {
    return list.get(position);
}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    LayoutHandler layoutHandler;
    View row = convertView;
    if (row == null)
    {
        LayoutInflater layoutInflater = (LayoutInflater) this.getContext().getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        row = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.row_layout,parent,false);
        layoutHandler = new LayoutHandler();
        layoutHandler.kod = (TextView)row.findViewById(R.id.t_kod);
        layoutHandler.den = (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.t_den);
        row.setTag(layoutHandler);
    }
    else
    {
        layoutHandler=(LayoutHandler) row.getTag();
    }
    DataProvider dataProvider = (DataProvider) this.getItem(position);
    layoutHandler.kod.setText(dataProvider.getKod());
    layoutHandler.den.setText(dataProvider.getDen());

        return row;
    }
}
```

**ActivityWhereIWanttheRetrievedData.xml**

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ScrollView
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:id="@+id/scrollView"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
        android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
        android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
        android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
        tools:context="jansoldat.formular100.MainActivity">


        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Úsek komunikace:"
            android:id="@+id/textView81"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:textSize="20dp"
            android:textColor="#870b0f"
            android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />

        <EditText
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/editText_Usek_komunikace"
            android:layout_below="@+id/textView81"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_alignParentEnd="true" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Kód úseku komunikace:"
            android:id="@+id/textView82"
            android:layout_column="0"
            android:textColor="#870b0f"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:layout_below="@+id/editText_Usek_komunikace"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
            android:layout_marginTop="15dp" />

        <EditText
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/editText2"
            android:layout_below="@+id/textView82"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_alignParentEnd="true" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Kódy sousedících objektů/ komunikací"
            android:id="@+id/textView83"
            android:layout_column="0"
            android:textColor="#870b0f"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:layout_below="@+id/editText2"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
            android:layout_marginTop="15dp" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="na počátku úseku komunikace:"
            android:id="@+id/textView84"
            android:layout_column="0"
            android:textColor="#870b0f"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:layout_below="@+id/textView83"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
            android:layout_alignRight="@+id/textView81"
            android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/textView81"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp" />

        <EditText
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/editText3"
            android:layout_below="@+id/textView84"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
            android:layout_alignRight="@+id/textView84"
            android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/textView84" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="na konci úseku komunikace:"
            android:id="@+id/textView85"
            android:layout_column="0"
            android:textColor="#870b0f"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:layout_below="@+id/textView83"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/textView86"
            android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/textView86"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp" />

        <EditText
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/editText4"
            android:layout_below="@+id/textView84"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
            android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/textView85"
            android:layout_alignStart="@+id/textView85" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Součást měřené trasy/ lokality:"
            android:id="@+id/textView86"
            android:layout_column="0"
            android:textColor="#870b0f"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:layout_below="@+id/editText3"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
            android:layout_marginTop="15dp" />

        <EditText
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/editText5"
            android:layout_below="@+id/textView86"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_alignParentEnd="true" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="GPS souřadnice"
            android:id="@+id/textView87"
            android:layout_column="0"
            android:textColor="#870b0f"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:layout_below="@+id/editText5"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
            android:layout_marginTop="15dp" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="počátek měřeného úseku:"
            android:id="@+id/textView88"
            android:layout_column="0"
            android:textColor="#870b0f"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:layout_below="@+id/textView87"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp" />

        <EditText
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/editText6"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
            android:inputType="numberDecimal"
            android:digits="0123456789,.°&apos;"
            android:layout_below="@+id/textView88"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="10dp" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="konec měřeného úseku:"
            android:id="@+id/textView89"
            android:layout_column="0"
            android:textColor="#870b0f"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:layout_below="@+id/editText6"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp" />

        <EditText
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/editText7"
            android:digits="0123456789,.°&apos;"
            android:inputType="numberDecimal"
            android:layout_below="@+id/textView89"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="10dp" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Mapové schéma:"
            android:id="@+id/textView90"
            android:layout_column="0"
            android:textColor="#870b0f"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:layout_below="@+id/editText7"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
            android:layout_marginTop="15dp" />

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="250dp"
            android:layout_height="250dp"
            android:id="@+id/imageView_mapa"
            android:contextClickable="false"
            android:adjustViewBounds="false"
            android:background="#850202"
            android:layout_below="@+id/textView90"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Měření provedl(i):"
            android:id="@+id/textView91"
            android:layout_column="0"
            android:textColor="#870b0f"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:layout_below="@+id/imageView_mapa"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
            android:layout_marginTop="15dp" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="dne:"
            android:id="@+id/textView92"
            android:layout_column="0"
            android:textColor="#870b0f"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:layout_above="@+id/editText8"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/textView86"
            android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/textView86" />

        <EditText
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:inputType="date"
            android:ems="10"
            android:id="@+id/editText8"
            android:layout_below="@+id/textView91"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
            android:layout_alignRight="@+id/textView88"
            android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/textView88" />

        <EditText
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/editText9"
            android:layout_below="@+id/textView92"
            android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/textView92"
            android:layout_alignStart="@+id/textView92"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_alignParentEnd="true" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Délka úseku komunikace:"
            android:id="@+id/textView93"
            android:layout_column="0"
            android:textColor="#870b0f"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
            android:layout_below="@+id/editText9"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp" />

        <EditText
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/editText10"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
            android:inputType="numberDecimal"
            android:digits="0123456789,.m"
            android:layout_below="@+id/textView93"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_alignParentEnd="true" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Typ komunikace:"
            android:id="@+id/textView94"
            android:layout_column="0"
            android:textColor="#870b0f"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:layout_below="@+id/editText10"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
            android:layout_marginTop="15dp" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Materiál povrchu:"
            android:id="@+id/textView95"
            android:layout_column="0"
            android:textColor="#870b0f"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:layout_below="@+id/radioGroup3"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
            android:layout_marginTop="15dp" />

        <RadioGroup
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:id="@+id/radioGroup3"
            android:layout_below="@+id/textView94"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp">

            <RadioButton
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="pás pro pěší (chodník)"
                android:id="@+id/radioButton"
                android:checked="false" />

            <RadioButton
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="stezka pro chodce (označeno značkou C07)"
                android:id="@+id/radioButton2"
                android:checked="false" />

            <RadioButton
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="stezka pro chodce a cyklisty ( označeno značkou C09 nebo C10)"
                android:id="@+id/radioButton3"
                android:checked="false" />

            <RadioButton
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="nezpevněná komunikace (pěšina, polní cesta...)"
                android:id="@+id/radioButton4"
                android:checked="false" />

            <RadioButton
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="pěší zóna (označeno značkou IP27)"
                android:id="@+id/radioButton5"
                android:checked="false" />

            <RadioButton
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="obytná zóna (označeno značkou IP26)"
                android:id="@+id/radioButton6"
                android:checked="false" />

            <RadioButton
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="pohyb po motoristické komunikaci (krajnice...)"
                android:id="@+id/radioButton7"
                android:checked="false" />
        </RadioGroup>

        <Spinner
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/spinner2"
            android:layout_below="@+id/textView95"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />

        <EditText
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/editText11"
            android:visibility="visible"
            android:layout_below="@+id/spinner2"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_alignParentEnd="true" />

    </RelativeLayout>


</ScrollView>
```

**EDIT:**

here is my updated code:

**DataListActivity.java**

```
public class DataListActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    ListView listView;
    SQLiteDatabase sqLiteDatabase;
    DbOperace dbOperace;
    Cursor cursor;
    ListDataAdapter listDataAdapter;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.data_list_layout);

        listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.lis_view);
        listDataAdapter = new ListDataAdapter(getApplicationContext(),R.layout.row_layout);
        listView.setAdapter(listDataAdapter);

        dbOperace = new DbOperace(getApplicationContext());
        sqLiteDatabase = dbOperace.getReadableDatabase();
        cursor = dbOperace.getInformations(sqLiteDatabase);

        if (cursor.moveToFirst())
        {
            do {

                String kod,den;
                kod = cursor.getString(0);
                den = cursor.getString(1);
                DataProvider dataProvider = new DataProvider(kod,den);
                listDataAdapter.add(dataProvider);

            }while (cursor.moveToNext());
        }

        listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(DataListActivity.this, RetrieveData.class);
                intent.putExtra("data", listView.getSelectedItemPosition());
                startActivity(intent);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

**Retrieve Data**

```
public class RetrieveData extends AppCompatActivity {
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_retrieve_data);
        Bundle bundle = getIntent().getExtras();
        if (bundle != null) {
            DataProvider dataProvider = bundle.getParcelable("data");
        }
    }
}
```

How should I now get into the retrieve activity data from database (which are not mention in code before [just in saving])?

Answer (score 0):

You had to write setOnitemclicklistener for the listview. Inside that get that position value from the list. Below is the code for OnItemClickListener,

```
    list.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
       @Override
       public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
          Intent intent = new Intent(DataListActivity.this, DetailActivity.class);
intent.putExtra("data", list.get(position);
startActivity(intent);
       } 
    });
```

And in DetailActivity class get the value as shown below.

```
Bundle bundle = getIntent().getExtras();
        if (bundle != null) {
            DataProvider  dataProvider = bundle.getParcelable("data");
}
```

In order to achieve this, you had to maintain the List in DataListActivity class itself. Also you had to implement Parcelable in your model class as shown below.

```
public class DataProvider implements Parcelable {

    private String kod;
    private String den;

    public String getKod() {
        return kod;
    }

    public void setKod(String kod) {
        this.kod = kod;
    }

    public String getDen() {
        return den;
    }

    public void setDen(String den) {
        this.den = den;
    }

    public DataProvider(String kod, String den)
    {
        this.kod=kod;
        this.den=den;

    }

    protected DataProvider(Parcel in) {
        kod = in.readString();
        den = in.readString();
    }

    @Override
    public int describeContents() {
        return 0;
    }

    @Override
    public void writeToParcel(Parcel dest, int flags) {
        dest.writeString(kod);
        dest.writeString(den);
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("unused")
    public static final Parcelable.Creator<DataProvider> CREATOR = new Parcelable.Creator<DataProvider>() {
        @Override
        public DataProvider createFromParcel(Parcel in) {
            return new DataProvider(in);
        }

        @Override
        public DataProvider[] newArray(int size) {
            return new DataProvider[size];
        }
    };
}
```

By this you can achieve easily. Hope this helps:)

Comment: Thank you so much!! But now, how should i fill the DetailActivity with data from database based on specific item click. And I change the setOnItemClickListener because android does not recognize get(position) method. `listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) { Intent intent = new Intent(DataListActivity.this, RetrieveData.class); intent.putExtra("data",listView.getSelectedItemPosition());        startActivity(intent);
            }
        });`

Comment: I don't know if i edit it right... I'm really confused